# How to count total number of Rating from the Extend Comment Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a WordPress Rating plugin from "http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/08/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/"

I would like to count the total number of rating and print that number under the Blog Post. Is this possible?

I added some customisation in this code.

```
<?php
// Add fields after default fields above the comment box, always visible
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'additional_fields' );

function additional_fields () {
    echo '<p class="comment-form-rating">'.
    '<label for="rating">'. __('Rating') . '<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <span class="commentratingbox">';

    for( $i=1; $i <= 5; $i++ )
        echo '<span class="commentrating"><input type="radio" checked name="rating" id="rating" value="'. $i .'"/>'. $i .' Star</span>';

    echo'</span></p>';
}

// Save the comment meta data along with comment
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['rating'] ) ) && ( $_POST['rating'] != '') )
    $rating = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['rating']);
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
}

// Add the filter to check if the comment meta data has been filled or not
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_comment_meta_data' );
function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['rating'] ) )
    wp_die( __( 'Error: You did not add your rating. Hit the BACK button of your Web browser and resubmit your comment with rating.' ) );
    return $commentdata;
}

//Add an edit option in comment edit screen 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_comment', 'extend_comment_add_meta_box' );
function extend_comment_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'title', __( 'Comment Metadata - Extend Comment' ), 'extend_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function extend_comment_meta_box ( $comment ) {
    $phone = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'phone', true );
    $title = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'title', true );
    $rating = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
    wp_nonce_field( 'extend_comment_update', 'extend_comment_update', false );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="rating"><?php _e( 'Rating: ' ); ?></label>
            <span class="commentratingbox">
            <?php for( $i=1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
                echo '<span class="commentrating"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="'. $i .'"';
                if ( $rating == $i ) echo ' checked="checked"';
                echo ' />'. $i .' </span>'; 
                }
            ?>
            </span>
    </p>
    <?php
}

// Update comment meta data from comment edit screen 
add_action( 'edit_comment', 'extend_comment_edit_metafields' );
function extend_comment_edit_metafields( $comment_id ) {
    if( ! isset( $_POST['extend_comment_update'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['extend_comment_update'], 'extend_comment_update' ) ) return;

    if ( ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) && ( $_POST['phone'] != '') ) : 
    $phone = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['phone']);
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone', $phone );
    else :
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone');
    endif;

    if ( ( isset( $_POST['title'] ) ) && ( $_POST['title'] != '') ):
    $title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title']);
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', $title );
    else :
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title');
    endif;

    if ( ( isset( $_POST['rating'] ) ) && ( $_POST['rating'] != '') ):
    $rating = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['rating']);
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
    else :
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating');
    endif;

}

// Add the comment meta (saved earlier) to the comment text 
// You can also output the comment meta values directly in comments template 
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'modify_comment');
function modify_comment( $text ){
    $plugin_url_path = WP_PLUGIN_URL;

    if( $commenttitle = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'title', true ) ) {
        $commenttitle = '<strong>' . esc_attr( $commenttitle ) . '</strong><br/>';
        $text = $commenttitle . $text;
    } 

    if( $commentrating = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true ) ) {
        $commentrating = '<p class="comment-rating">    <img src="'. $plugin_url_path .
        '/ExtendComment/images/'. $commentrating . 'star.gif"/><br/>Rating: <strong>'. $commentrating .' / 5</strong></p>';
        $text = $text . $commentrating;
        return $text;       
    } else {
        return $text;       
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would go something like this. Appending the total for all ratings:

```
if( !is_admin() )
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'content_so_23778986' );

function content_so_23778986( $content )
{
    if( !is_single() )
        return $content;

    # Get all comments from current post
    $comms = get_comments( array( 'post_id'=>get_the_ID() ) );
    $counter = null;
    if( $comms )
    {
        $total = count( $comms );
        # Iterate all comments and add its rating to the counter
        foreach( $comms as $c )
        {
            $rating = (int) get_comment_meta( $c->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
            $counter +=  $rating;
        }
        # Calculate and print the totals
        $counter = '<br />' . $counter / $total  . ' de 5';
    }
    return $content . $counter;
}
```